# 64-bit multiplicative hashing

Tags: c, hash

I'm working on fast 64-bit hash. Many existing secure hash functions are too way slow, some non-cryptographic hash functions like FNV are just bad.

Well, I came up with a FNV-like hash:

```
UINT64 hash=0;

// for each input byte
hash=(hash^(input_byte+1))*HASH_PRIME;
```

Main question is about `HASH_PRIME`. Often, we may see a *"golden ratio"* term for multiplicative hashing.
For 64-bit hash, golden ratio is `0x9e3779b97f4a7c13`.

I tested the 32-bit golden ratio for period in `PRNG`:

```
DWORD hash=0;
// loop
hash=(hash^1)*0x9e3779b9;
rnd_out=hash>>24;
```

A good value here may produce the period of `0xFFFFFFFF` - i.e. max possible. This golden ratio produces notably smaller period.

or just

```
DWORD hash=~0;
// loop
hash*=0x9e3779b9;
rnd_out=hash>>24;
```

And again, a good enough multiplier can produce period of `0x3FFFFFFF` bytes. Golden ratio here produces again much shorter period.

Never tested the 64-bit primes - too computationally expensive.

Is period important for my hash? And where to find a good 64-bit `HASH_PRIMES` and how to test such stuff?

Comment: Using a prime is usually overkill, but FWIW the nearest primes to your constant are `11400714819323198549` and `2654435741` for 64 and 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this is as an exercise? otherwise I would advise having a looking at well known hash functions as Bob Jenkin's lookup8 and lookup family (http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/ ) and Austin Appleby's murmur http://code.google.com/p/smhasher/ (a speed killer and my favorite). Good hash functions are hard to build... and if you are after a rolling type of hash, Rabin fingerprints are hard to beat.
And to make sure that your hashes are decent if you really want to roll your own, use either Appleby and Jenkins hash tests (torture and smhasher )

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the first two examples.  But in the third to get a full period out of the code you need to add an odd number.  Otherwise this will have a maximum period of 65537, It could be as low as 3.  There may even be a fixed point.

Wherever you got the 0x3FFFFFFF for a good period is not correct.  One of the Knuth volumes discusses this in excessive detail.

The multiplier must be of the form   4n+1   and there must be an odd addend

Answer (score 0):

*Generally* nobody pays much attention to the period of a hash given a stream of zeroes.  CRC has historically been an exception because it's often used in a hardware context where seeing a device output stuck at zero is a common failure mode which you don't want to overlook, and in that case your CRC will spin around in whatever period it supports, and a short period means it's comparatively likely to arrive back at its starting point when the output unsticks.

However, the strongest CRC polynomials do *not* have full-cycle periods, because other properties are more important.